# Angular Datatable add icon Edit on first column with columndef

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable

I got a problem when develop datatable in Angular. I have table like this

```
| Action | Name | Address |
(Edit)   | Alex | Gold Street 2nd
```

I want to add edit icon on first column. Sometime ago, I also try datatable without Angular like this:

```
'columnDefs': [{
         'targets': 0,
         'searchable':false,
         'orderable':false,
         'className': 'dt-body-center',
         'render': function (data, type, full, meta){
             return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="'
                + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
         }
      },
```

Now I also developed for Angular that using ui-options. This is my script:

```
  <table ui-jq="dataTable" ui-options="{
          sAjaxSource: BASE_URL+'index.php/customer/showall',
          aoColumns: [
            { mData: 'id' },
            { mData: 'name' },
            { mData: 'company' },
            { mData: 'email' },
            { mData: 'phone' }
          ],
          columnDefs: [
        { targets: [0], orderable: false, render: function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
      return data;
    } }
    ],
        }" class="table table-striped m-b-none">
```

I got an error on Columndefs. Anyone please have a solution for it? Lets sharing guys! :) Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use [angular-datatables](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/), using "vanilla" jQuery dataTables in angular is guaranteed to doom.  If you not want to do that, then render your table with `ng-repeat`, and insert a checkbox in that process, then initialize the dataTable in a `$timeout`.

Comment: okay i will try it. im using "angulr" template from themeforest.